# JSP не транслирует в HTML

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, controller, config

Даже не знаю чего и показать ...

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver urlBasedViewResolver(){
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/views/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/");
}
```

...

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edit word</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="edit" method="post">        
    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="${id}">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/words/edit",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editWord(Model model, @RequestParam(required = false) String userID){
    model.addAttribute("words",wordService.getAll());
    return "/words/edit";
}
```

Отображает как будто JSP открыли браузере. 
[image: That return my controller]

[image: structure of pages]

Comment: В методе `editWord` добавьте вывод в консоль `System.out.println("work")`, и при вызове этого метода в консоли что-нибудь выводится?

Comment: @MrFylypenko Все контроллеры срабатывают в том числе и этот. Там выполняется `wordService.getAll()`  а hibernate в свою очередь отображает запросы.

Comment: Вы формируете атрибут `words`, а где на jsp странице он используется?

Comment: @MrFylypenko Нигде, Вы правы, это только для примера. И по-моему не обязательно на странице использовать все выше объявленные атрибуты?

Answer (score 0):

Уберите

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/views/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/views/");
```

Вы инструктируете spring считать ваши jsp-шки статическими файлами.